# The text over the image occupy the link click area

Tags: html, css

There is an image nested in an `<a>` tag, and some text (title and description) on it:

```
<figure class="post-image">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://example.com/book.jpg">
            </a>

            <figcaption>
                <span>This is the title</span>
                <p>This is the paragraph.</p>
            </figcaption>
</figure>

figcaption{
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    font-size:20px;
} 
figure{
    position:relative
}
```

The problem is that the texts nested in `<span>` and `<p>` tags, occupy the click area of the `<a>` tag.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mhyan/1/

Comment: What is that you want? You want the link to work along with text over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) on the absolutely positioned `<figcaption>` in order for it to be prevented from being the target of mouse events.

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Mhyan/4/)**.

```css
figcaption {
    /* other styles here... */
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This way it behaves just like you're only hovering the anchor tag having an image.

It's worth noting that `pointer-events` property [is supported in **IE9+**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility). However there is a [polyfill](https://github.com/kmewhort/pointer_events_polyfill) for that.

---

Alternatively you could wrap the `<figcaption>` by the the anchor tag to include the nested elements. (**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Mhyan/5/)**).

But in this case you might need to style the anchor tag containing paragraph/span to act as a normal text. (**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Mhyan/6/)**).

```css
.post-image a,
.post-image a:visited,
.post-image a:hover,
.post-image a:active {
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         <figure class="post-image">
         <a href="#">
            <img src="http://example.com/book.jpg">
            <figcaption>
               <span>This is the title</span>
               <p>This is the paragraph.</p>
           </figcaption>
         </a>
         </figure>
```

Try this above code..

Answer (score 0):

The `figcaption` has a `position:absolute` which positions this section over the top of the `a` tag. Try removing it.

Comment: So I want the figcaption to be on the image. I don't want it at the bottom or top, do you have any idea that keep the figcaption on the image and also the link clickable?

Comment: @FarzadBayan end the anchor tag after `figcaption` ends.